# How to fix element positioning in WooCommerce product page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, themes

I am using Astra theme for my shop and after the latest theme update, the elements on the product pages are messed up...

(I create a child theme to prevent these update issues to happen again)

Now all elements under the Add To Cart button are in one line and have no line break anymore.
[elements are out of place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHRP6.png)

Can somebody tell me how I can fix this problem, please?

This is an example product page of my website where this issue occurs: https://solarshopus.com/product/100w-solar-panel-12v-solar-cell-10a-60a-controller/

Best regards,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

you can make it custom via copy woocommerce files in theme.
like if you want to change product page
just copy template from woocommerce plugin and add it in your child theme in woocommerce folder.